# How to sort a 1:1 object map in Angular JS ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

Is there a way to sort a 1:1 object map in angular.js using filters (or any other method) within a ng-repeat block?

I have:

```
obj:{
     a:3,
     c:5,
     d:1,
     g:15
}
```

Essentially I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in obj | orderBy:'value'"> {{ item.value }}</div>
```

I would like to be able to sort that data representation either by key or value. I know that angular OrderBy will only sort arrays so it won't sort that object. However, if I could turn that object into an array of objects with key and value as properties (preferably using a filter called 'toArray' ):

```
var arr = [
  { 
     key:'a',
     value:'3'
  },
  {
    key:'c',
    value:5
  },
  ....
]
```

then I could use something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in obj | toArray | orderBy:'value'"> {{ item.value }}</div>
```

However, any attempt to write such a filter has produced a *'10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!'* error as it updates the new array of objects on every iteration.

What is the best (or any) solution to sorting a 1:1 object map without having to restructure the data in the controller?

Comment: Please provide the code to your `toArray` filter, so we can go from there. A stab in the dark: does your `toArray` handle cycles properly? Some AngularJS objects have cycles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [angular-underscore](https://github.com/floydsoft/angular-underscore) which introduces underscore functions to angular.js. Then you can write code like:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in values(obj) | orderBy:identity"> {{ item }}</div>
```

to get only values; or

```
<div ng-repeat="item in pairs(obj) | orderBy:last"> Key: {{ item[0] }}; Value: {{item[1]}}</div>
```

to get both keys and values.

It's really easy. Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Zb4XpaQUXZ8nZJqR493b?p=preview

Comment: this looks promising, I see it orders the list by value from lowest to highest value. how would you reverse that order?...from highest value to lowest value

Comment: @user1394625 just add the `:reverse` parameter like this: `<div ng-repeat="item in values(obj) | orderBy:identity:true"> {{ item }}</div>`. You can refer to AngularJS doc [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about just creating the array initially in your controller like so?

```
$scope.items = [];
for(var key in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        $scope.items.push({ key: key, value: obj[key] });
    }
}
```

Then iterate over `items`?

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items|orderBy:'value'">{{ item.value }}</div>
```

At least then you are only populating the array one time. This could be an issue if the initial object comes from a request or something, but I guess you could quite easily populate in the callback of said request.

Comment: At the moment that is the only solution I have...to do it in the controller. I was hoping there was a way to do it in the view. It's not just one object that is structured that way so I'd have to run each object through a function in the controller. Not a deal breaker but it looks cleaner just piping through a filter in the view.

Comment: you could likely do it as a filter or directive somehow, but it wouldn't really be great for performance. I imagine it'd keep evaluating it every time the watcher is triggered, so you'd be generating that array *every time*. Maybe just make a service you inject into your controller to do this? (like Utils.somehelper)